# No module named xxxx. How to import relative path?

Tags: python-3.x, module, relative-import

I have created a simplified version as to focus solely on getting the relative path to work. This is my file structure:

```
|
-project
   |-package1
   |    |--page
   |    |-__init__
   |
   |-package2
        |-test
        |-__init__
```

I am trying to import page into test. However, I get the error that package1 is not a module. Below I have typed all that are in my code. Very simple. I am just trying to import page into test. Is there anything I am missing (file or page set up) that is preventing me from importing?

page.py

---

```
one='half'
two='ling'
```

tests.py

---

```
import os
import sys

three = (one+two)
print(three)
```

Comment: How do you run the code?

Comment: I am using Python 3.7 and VS code when I run it

Comment: Try running it from the command line and update your question. Also I do not see the import in `tests.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "from package1 import page" into your test.py? Or "from package1.page import page"?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. It gives me the "No Module named Project1" still. I have tried several different ways to import my page.py file. So I am starting to wonder if there's something missing with my set up... Or maybe I just tried all the wrong ways! haha

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

When `import` something, Python Interpreter search in the following places:

> - Built-ins
> - Current Directory
> - $PYTHONPATH, environment variable
> - some other directory related to the installation

The last three make up to be `sys.path`.

In your case, to import package1 into some script in package2, there's 2 ways:

> 1. Add `project` path into PYTHONPATH.
> 2. Dynamically append `project` path into `sys.path`

I guess you would appreciate the latter solution, just add

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
```

in front of everything and it will work.

*Plus: It's kind of inconvenient to use the module not inside the current directory though. I've seen only a few actual python project, and What I've seen is some of them use a single `main.py` in the **project root** to run the whole project, including test-cases. Maybe this structure is more recommended.*

Hope it helps~

---

Original Answer:

This dir structure works fine on my computer with:

```py
import package.page as page
page.foo() # a function in page
```

Could I have a guess: your current working directory may be not under your project directory.

To check, test about this:

```py
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

If the output is not your current directory, that's my case. I used to mess with this before.

To avoid this, you can:

1. `cd` to your directory before running Python
2. run `os.chdir(...)` in your code, which is to change your working directory.

If not this case, please provide more information.

Comment: So I did print(os.getcwd()). I got the directory I wanted: "c:\users\username\project". But it still gives me that "project" or "package is not a module". I am using Python 3.7. I have installed and uninstalled Python several times. When I run cmd, type Python, it does recognize that I have Python 3.7. (I have been using VS code to run my code)

Comment: Maybe try add `sys.path.append(your_project_path)` before your import. though I dont think it needed when you're at root path of project. the input path should be relative to your `os.getcwd` or simply absolute path.

Comment: So I have been going off on what you suggested and I think I might know what is going on. But I want to run this by you to see how you got yours to work. Are you clicking the test.py and running the code from there? Or are you running the codes on a different file?

Comment: I ask this because I am not used to Python and I am starting to wonder if I am missing some basics in development that are different from what I learned. I am a QA and I normally work with Javascript using QA tools. I'll give you an example of how I did everything in Javascript: package1 is what holds my xpath info and functions. package2 holds my tests. And when I want to run my tests, I would run them WITHIN package2. Is that not possible with Python?

Comment: guess I get what you want. It's possible, though there may be more _pythonic_ way. Please check my update in detail.